# How to make Node wait for promise to complete in an infinite while loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The snoowrap library returns a promise when a function a call is made using it. I would like for node to wait until the call is complete and then execute its callback function. How can I do that? I've tried different forms of using setTimeout, wait.for library, and other solutions but none have worked.

```
        while(1){
            for (var i = 0; i < allowableTimes.length; i++) {
                if (new Date().getTime() == allowableTimes[i].getTime()) {
                    reddit.getHot('aww', {limit: 1}).then(sendToSlack);
                }
            }
        }

function sendToSlack(res){
    var url = res[0].url;
    var title = res[0].title;

    bot.sendWebhook({
        username: "bawwt",
        icon_emoji: ":smile_cat:",
        text: "<" + url + "|" + title + ">",
        channel: "#random"
    });
}
```

SOLVED: Here is the solution below that worked for me based on the code in the accepted answer:

```
if (!err) {
            reddit.getHot('aww', {limit: 1}).then(handleReddit);
    }
});

function handleReddit(res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < allowableTimes.length; i++) {
        if (validTime(allowableTimes[i])) {
            sendToSlack(res);
        }
    }
        queryReddit();
}

function validTime(allowableTime) {
    var date = new Date();

    var hour = date.getHours();
    var minute = date.getMinutes();

    var allowableHour = allowableTime.getHours();
    var allowableMinute = allowableTime.getMinutes();

    return hour == allowableHour && minute == allowableMinute;
}

function queryReddit() {
    setTimeout(function() {reddit.getHot('aww', {limit: 1}).then(handleReddit);}, 60000);
}

function sendToSlack(res){
            var url = res[0].url;
            var title = res[0].title;

            bot.sendWebhook({
                username: "bawwt",
                icon_emoji: ":smile_cat:",
                text: "<" + url + "|" + title + ">",
                channel: "#random"
            });
}
```

Comment: Assuming you mean `reddit.getHot()` call. Are you sure you want to wait for the call to complete? I would think that's what the `sendToSlack` callback is for. In node, you shouldn't block the rest of the server on a callback. 
Instead, you should make `sendToSlack` a recursive function that deals with the callback and fires off another call to `reddit.getHot()` and get rid of the loop

Comment: The sendToSlack function uses the result from the reddit.getHot function but the function never completes and node seems to loop over it very quickly. I'll add the contents of sendToSlack if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason your callback never gets called is because you never give the node runtime a chance to do that. It's a single thread and you are infinitely using it up with your `while(1)`. It will not have a chance to actually handle the resolving network call that the promise responds to as you are keeping the thread busy with more

As mentioned in the comment: In node, you shouldn't block the rest of the server on a callback. Instead, you should make sendToSlack a recursive function that deals with the callback and fires off another call to reddit.getHot() and get rid of the loop

Conceptual code:

```
var allowableTimes = 20;
var times = 0;
function handleReddit(res)
{
    sendToSlack(res);
    times = times + 1;
    if(times < allowableTimes)
    {
        reddit.getHot('aww', {limit: 1}).then(handleReddit);
    }
}

reddit.getHot('aww', {limit: 1}).then(handleReddit);
```

Just off hand code

Comment: Would't this cause me to reach the rate limit for the reddit api and if allowableTimes is high enough it'll hit the max function call stack size?

Comment: @uioporqwerty That's a separate issue and it's up to you. If you want to rate limit, have some timeout. I personally don't see a problem doing it this way if you have a low number of `allowableTimes` which looks like you should have in this instance. If you are going to run something more than the times of the call stack max (which is ridiculously high by the way). Then you can reset the stack size by a timeout function.

Comment: @uioporqwerty 
Also i don't believe that in this case this will actually happen no matter how high allowable times is. The method call will not go on the stack. `reddit.getHot` takes a callback so it should be a new stack produced on the next call. If `reddit.getHot()` happened synchronously then this would be a problem

Comment: Even if it is supposed to be an infinite loop, you should always `return` your promise from the function (in this case the `reddit.getHot(…).then(…)` from `handleReddit`) to make it chainable (and continue when all 20 requests are made)